# GLCullFace for front and back triangles ? iPhone OPENGL ES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, 3d

Is there a way to use GLCullFace on an object which is made up of inconsistent facing triangles ? I.e some are facing backwards and some forwards ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is face culling supposed to know which triangles are facing the wrong direction? You should fix your mesh!

Comment: I thought OPENGL was magic ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mesh is closed, you might get away with setting: `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`.
I would recommend fixing the winding orders of the triangles however - it'll save a lot of trouble later.

Comment: Thanks - is there any way to check which way any given triangle is facing ?

Comment: You can perform a signed area test. OpenGL specifies this test for culling, though it may implement it in another (equivalent) way.